# (Python 3.4 Tkinter) Frame issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I run this code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

fr = Frame(root, width=50, height=50).pack()
b = Button(fr, text='Click').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

button 'b' is outside the frame 'fr', acting as if i wrote `root` instead of `fr` in `b = Button(fr, ...`.

Answer (score 3):

You should execute pack on the object returned from Frame and Button.

```
fr = Frame(root, width=50, height=50)
fr.pack()
b = Button(fr, text='Click')
b.pack()
```

Otherwise, your fr and b are None, i.e. they take values returned by `pack()` which is None.